# Table View Programming

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Why can't I add a subview to table view cell's content view?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier ";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 70, 15)];
        label.text=@"Name:";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
    return [cell autorelease];

}
```

Comment: Because something is wrong. (Provide details if you want good answers.)

Comment: You certainly can! If you have some problems with it post your code here - it is really impossible to help you without seeing it.

Comment: Well he cannot update the question with more information if you guys close it :)

Comment: i added a code snippet, i really dont understand why i cant do this

Comment: More code is required. The code snippet in the question looks correct, so the problem might not be there. The problem may be with where the cell is created or dequeued from the table view. Also, where is this code being called? Ideally you should be calling it from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but there's no way to tell from this little code. I voted to reopen so you can provide more details.

Comment: i have updated the whole method now

Comment: Well, for starters there is a problem with memory management. Notice that first you attempt to dequeue a table cell from the table view. If a cell with the ID exists, it will be returned, and it is autoreleased, so you don't need to worry about its memory. If a cell doesn't exist you create one using the alloc/init method, but you don't autorelease it (like you should). You then do `return [cell autorelease];' which is fine for your newly created cell, but if the cell was dequeued from the table, you're probably double autoreleasing it which will cause a crash later on.

Comment: Also, I notice that you're creating a cell with the default style, which already provides a text label for you to use, you don't need to add your own as a subview. You can access the cell's label by using the textLabel property. While the textLabel property itself is read only, it's properties are as if it was a normal UILabel, allowing you to set its text, textColor, font, alignment, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a problem of memory management.

Consider this statement:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellTableIdentifier];
```

According to the [Cocoa memory management rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), this is not an `alloc`/`new`/`copy` method, i.e. you don't own the `cell`, so you should *not* `-release` it after finish using it. However, the next statement (assume `cell != nil`):

```
return [cell autorelease];
```

will make the `cell` be released (some time later), causing a double-release of the cell (some time later). Therefore you should simply `return cell;`.

Now what if `cell == nil`? Inside the `if` branch, you wrote

```
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
```

Since the `cell` is created with `alloc`, you are responsible to `-release` it. But since you're going to return it to others, you have to relinquish the ownership while avoid it not being deallocated immediately. This is where `-autorelease` is used, to temporarily transfer the ownership to an "autorelease pool" so other code can have a chance to retake the ownership (`-retain` it) before it got flushed into voidness.

In the other words you should replace this statement with `cell = [[[...] autorelease];`.

Similarly, you should `-release` the `label` because it is `-alloc`-ed and you are no longer own it. However, you don't need to `-autorelease` because you are sure there is already another owner (`cell.contentView`).

To summarize, you should rewrite the code as:

```
 static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier ";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 70, 15)];
    label.text=@"Name:";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}
return cell;
```

---

BTW, you can use `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` (like the address book) to avoid messing with the view hierarchy.